# use placeholders for column names when using pipe operator

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, tidyverse

I have a table called `Dec20`, and two columns called `FEEL_a_W77` and `FEEL_b_W77`

Instead of tediously repeating column names like so...

`Dec20 %>% select(FEEL_a_W77) %>% group_by(FEEL_a_W77) %>% summarize(n=n())`

`Dec20 %>% select(FEEL_b_W77) %>% group_by(FEEL_b_W77) %>% summarize(n=n())`

...I want to do something like:

`colname <- FEEL_a_W77              //and repeat this later for FEEL_b_W77`

`Dec20 %>% select(colname) %>% group_by(colname) %>% summarize(n=n())`

This doesn't work (*"Error: object 'FEEL_a_W77' not found"*).

How can I make this work? Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You’ve just encountered the tidyverse’s non-standard evaluation (NSE). Write a function that takes two parameters, `data` and `colname`. Inside the function, “embrace” `colname`(`{{ colname }}`). Passing `data` as the first argument will allow you to use your function in pipes.

Comment: @Limey Thanks, this worked: `my_function <- function(data, colname) {
  data %>% 
    select({{colname}}) %>% 
 group_by({{colname}}) %>% 
    summarize(n=n())
}`